# Why is the orbit of the Earth around the Sun very intricate?

Tags: orbital-motion, earth, solar-system, stability

The movement of the earth around the sun is very Goldilocky. Did it happen over the years as the orbit of earth averaged out into how it is now? Is there any chance of it (orbit) changing by itself in the future without the interference of external factors?

Also how is it so stable? And what drives it? Is the sun pulling it once it is far away, gains speed, goes around the sun and as it goes away it again loses speed due to the sun's gravity and the whole cycle repeats?

Comment: I think what you are wanting to ask is, "How _stable_ is the orbit of the Earth around the Sun?" - i.e. how much motive force does it take to change it, how does the size of the changes depend upon the applied force and, moreover, can it "recover" from such a change so as to regain its original orbit, if that change is not too large. Is this right?

Comment: Sorry but I wanted to ask what I asked. If disturbed slightly will we eventually fall into the sun or drift slowly away from the sun?

Comment: While this is indeed an interesting question, terms like "disturbed", "what would happen", and "can we restore it again" are rather difficult to parse into something that can be approached with math and reason. Can you define the terms in your question more precisely?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist: Yep, that's what I'm after - this question needs to be delineated more precisely or it will be soon closed.

Comment: Ohh, I am new, sorry, I wanted to add to my question How stable is the orbit of the earth around the sun?, But I really wanted to know how come the orbit is so perfect? If indeed it is perfect, then in what ways can a slight change affect it?

Comment: @RajkumarMaurya What are you referring to when you say "perfect"?

Comment: I meant that the orbit has been stable for the past 4.5 billion years and will stay so for the future years.

Comment: Please read : https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

Orbits around the sun are ellipses. Any small perturbation will produce another elliptic orbit. So in this sense they are stable: they do not change their shape greatly unless one adds enough energy to turn the orbit into a parabola or hyperbola, which are unbound. So that Earth has retained its orbit over 4.5 billion years is not strange. Even big meteor impacts will just nudge the orbit but not change its nature.

The reason for this is how Newtonian gravity works: because the force scales as $1/r^2$ bound orbits are closed ([Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem)).

Comment: Did the movement of the earth's revolution average out over a long period of time from it's formation to give it the orbit it orbits today?

Comment: @RajkumarMaurya - During the early period of the solar system (more than 4 billion years ago) planetary orbits were less stable because of a large number of planetesimals hitting them, and the outer planets migrating inward due to remaining gas from the solar nebula. But since then the orbit has likely been unchanged.

Comment: @AndersSandberg You might want to define "unchanged"; in reality, several parameters oscillate with small magnitudes, like the eccentricity, apsidal angle, and inclination.

Answer (score -4):

First, the sun has a large amount of protons on the plasma, so it has a positive charge.Next, the ionosphere of the earth is positive and the surface is negative.The charge of the sun and the earth has been confirmed in mainstream science.

As the Earth approaches the perihelion, the effect of the solar wind increases the positive ionosphere.The Earth moves away from the sun, as the positive force of the sun increases.

As the solar wind decreases as the earth goes to aphelion point, the positive charge of the earth decreases and the repulsive force also decreases, so the earth approaches the sun.

As the earth approaches the sun, the positive charge increases and moves away, and as it goes away, the positive charge decreases and approaches.There is also the influence of the solar wind's standing waves that the solar oscillation makes, but if I write this it will be criticized for not being mainstream science, so let's stop it.

Comment: Do you have references?